# how can I use dfd,dtd and soprtr variable into another action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razorengine

[HttpPost]

```
     public ActionResult crbtmis(string submitbuttonoperator, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string operatorname)
     {
        DateTime dfd = fromdate;
        DateTime dtd = todate;
        string soprtr = operatorname;
         if (Session["user"] != null && Session["user"].ToString() == "MISADMIN")
         {

             switch (submitbuttonoperator)
             {
                 case "Export":
                     return (ExportOprtrlist( fromdate, todate, operatorname));
                 case "Search":
                     return (SearchByOperator());
                 default:
                     return (View("LogOn"));
             }
         }
         else
         {
             return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
         }
     }
```

I have defined three variable named as dfd,dtd and soprtr and want to use these variable into another ActionResult. Now please help me how will I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your action, you can use other action that contains some parameters:

```
public ActionResult crbtmis(string submitbuttonoperator, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string operatorname)
    {
       //..your code
       return RedirectToAction("OtherAction", new { dfd  = dfd, dtd = dtd, soprtr = soprtr });
    }
```